# How do I make Google Chrome allow CORS?

Tags: mixed-content

I have the following code on a (IIS) server as test1.htm.

```html
<script>

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.102/test2.htm", false);
    request.send();

    alert(request.response);

</script>
```

The file test2.htm just contains some simple text, "Hello World".  When I navigate Chrome to test1.htm using HTTP, to no surprise I get an alert popup saying, Hello World.  Life is good.

However, when I change HTTP to HTTPS for test1.htm, the request to test2.htm initiates a cross-domain violation, which it should.

But, I do have an extension named, "Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin" installed and turned on.  I'm new to CORS, but my understanding is that Chrome should now initiate a CORS process, perhaps a pre-flight check?  I see nothing.

Using the F12 debugger tool, I see that the request for test2.htm is flagged in red and its status marked as "blocked: mixed content", which is what I would expect if I did NOT have the CORS extension.  But I do...

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Curt

Update:  I'm using Chrome version 88.0.4324.190 under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out that example doesn't just create a cross-domain violation; it also creates a mixed-content violation.  That is, mixing http with https.  It's also known as insecure content for which there's a site-specific setting within Chrome.  Once that is set, the browser then allows the http request, but then expects a "simple" CORS response.